# Jquery mobile listview formated text not working through php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-mobile

I have the following function in Javascript.

```
function showInfo(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
} 

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","information.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I have created a select so that once something is chosen it will display a list.

```
<ul>
        <li><select name="days" id="days" onchange="showInfo(this.value)" data-native-menu="false">
            <option value="">  select   </option>
            <option value="1"> option 1 </option>
            <option value="2"> option 2 </option>
        </select></li>
</ul>
```

The information.php takes the value and querys a database to get the infor I want in a list. This all works fine, however when I want to show the list it comes out with the incorrect format.

```
echo '
<ul data-role="listview">
<li>
    <h3>Author:'.$the_author.'</h3>
    <p><b>Description:</b>'.$description.'</p>
    <p class="ui-li-aside">Last update:'.$date.'</p>
</li>
    //Etc.
</ul>
';
```

Now the list displayed should be simillar to the one from jquery mobile demos (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/lists/lists-formatting.html)

however it comes out looking like a standard html list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are dynamically creating the `<UL>` element and not just the listitems, you need to call enhanceWithin() (http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/) on txtHint after setting its HTML

Instead of this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

Try

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        $('#txtHint').append(xmlhttp.responseText).enhanceWithin();
    }
}
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Q67b7/)** with a mock AJAX call

Comment: Where should that be added exactly.

Comment: I can't figure out if it goes in the javascript, or in my php code. I am just getting to grips with this at the minute. Sorry that it is so basic a question

Comment: It is a JavaScript statement that has to run after the listview items have been added. If I understand your code... after the line document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; in the onreadystatechange (isn't that where you are adding the items?)

Comment: yes, however it isn't formating the list. I have added an id to my list in the php file (echo "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' id='infolist'>";) and have added the line $(#infolist").listview("refresh"); in the javascript

Comment: $("#infolist").listview("refresh"); should be correct (i assume missing quote before the # was a typo). You could try adding a setTimeout to delay it and see if it is a timing issue...  I don't really know how your project is setup, so it is hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: I don't believe it's a timing issue. There isnt much going on outside of what I have posted above. The information is all correct, just un-formatted.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Because you are creating the UL element as well as the LIs, you just need to call enhanceWithin() on txtHint after setting its html.

Comment: Thank you for the continued help. however it still doesn't seem to change the formatting. and I aim to refresh the list. not append to the list.

Comment: you can change append() to html() to refresh. enhanceWithin is for jQM 1.4, are you using that version? For 1.3 use trigger("create") - http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Q67b7/2/

Comment: That is perfect, I was using JQM 1.3.2
Upgraded to 1.4.0 and it works perfectly. Thank you for all the help